# Calculate a sum from information contained in a variable

Tags: php

How do I process a calculation using information stored in one variable? I want to let people enter a calculation into a form, and then they will get the answer. If someone enters 25 * 10, they will be told the answer is 250.

Comment: You may be tempted to use `eval()`, but DON'T! Never `eval()` as string that was entered by a user... You will have to build some kind of nightmareish string parser. This will be easy for simple `int * int`, `int + int` etc, but as soon as you get something more complicated, e.g. `(int * float) / int` it becomes much more difficult. Good luck...

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is "php math parser". This might help you: http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/package/2695.html. Didn't use it yet, looks ok though.

Please spare yourself a lot of trouble and don't use eval(). ;-)

UPDATE: I will need something like this too, so I took the time and found another one: http://www.bestcode.com/html/math_parser_for_php.html. It is not free though.

Answer (score -1):

you can do your own parser, or use the [eval function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php).

But please make sure to not allow random code execution on your server. some people would love to do a `shell_exec('rm *')` or something like that.

alternativly you could use [wolfram-alha api](http://products.wolframalpha.com/developers/) or something equivalent, if you don't need to store the result. (even then, you could send the result back to your server with ajax)

Comment: -1. NEVER `eval()` user input. To build something that will strip out all possible malicious code from the input would be much more difficult that just building an expression parser.

Comment: I never said he *should* do it. But we are supposed to be responsible grown ups...